# Android Browser crashes with Google Site Search

Tags: jquery, android, html, search

I am using Google Site Search on my site, which works fine in every browser. But I wanted to use my own input elements so I could put a custom search bar in my top navigation. I found a script that allows me to do so, and it works by appending "?q=" to the URL. The script on the search landing page the takes the query and injects it into the a new Google search field. The URL ends up looking something like this:

www.website.com/search/?q=query

This works in every browser except on Android mobile devices.

Here is the script for my custom search bar in my top nav:

```
<form onsubmit="return submitQuery()" id="search-form">
<input autocomplete="off" id="search" type="text" name="q" maxlength="100">
    <button type="submit" id="searchSubmit">Search</button>
</form>
<script>
    function submitQuery() {
        if ($('#search').val()=='Search') {
        alert('Please enter a search term');
    return false;
        }
        else {
            window.location = '/search/?q='
            + encodeURIComponent(
            document.getElementById('search').value);
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is the script on my search page

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en', style : google.loader.themes.MINIMALIST});
  /**
   * Extracts the users query from the URL.
   */ 
  function getQuery() {
    var url = '' + window.location;
    var queryStart = url.indexOf('?') + 1;
    if (queryStart > 0) {
      var parts = url.substr(queryStart).split('&');
      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (parts[i].length > 2 && parts[i].substr(0, 2) == 'q=') {
          return decodeURIComponent(
              parts[i].split('=')[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        }
      }
    }
    return '';
  }

  function onLoad() {
    // Create a custom search control that uses a CSE restricted to
    // code.google.com
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl(
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // this is the unique search engine ID

    var drawOptions = new google.search.DrawOptions();
    drawOptions.setAutoComplete(true);

    // Draw the control in content div
    customSearchControl.draw('results', drawOptions);
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);

    // Run a query
    customSearchControl.execute(getQuery());

    customSearchControl.setLinkTarget(google.search.Search.LINK_TARGET_SELF);

// Maximum length of query is 100 characters
$('.gsc-input').attr('maxlength', '100');

  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
</script>
```

How can I get this to stop crashing on Android devices? Let me know if I need to clear any of this up.

Comment: how its the crash? did you get some response from server? the browser crash? did you try using a default page instead /?q=value?

Comment: Actually, I just discovered why it was breaking. It has to do with the custom @font-face font that is being applied to the text within the search results.

Answer (score 1):

You can often find the cause of Android browser crashes by inspecting [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html).